# Why does CSharpExtensions.ClassifyConversion return an explicit reference conversion for object / string?

Tags: c#, roslyn

The [CSharpExtensions.ClassifyConversion(Compilation, ITypeSymbol, ITypeSymbol)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpextensions.classifyconversion?view=roslyn-dotnet#microsoft-codeanalysis-csharp-csharpextensions-classifyconversion(microsoft-codeanalysis-compilation-microsoft-codeanalysis-itypesymbol-microsoft-codeanalysis-itypesymbol)) method returns an explicit reference conversion if called with the special type object as `source` and the special type string as `destination` argument:

```cs
var objectTypeSymbol = context.Compilation.GetSpecialType(SpecialType.System_Object);
var stringTypeSymbol = context.Compilation.GetSpecialType(SpecialType.System_String);
var conversion = context.Compilation.ClassifyConversion(objectTypeSymbol, stringTypeSymbol);
```

As far as I know C# doesn't specify a built in object to string conversion: [C# language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions). Why does it return an explicit reference conversion and what does it imply? How would the c# syntax of such a conversion look like? If `ClassifyConversion` is called with an empty user defined class as `source` argument and the string special type  as `destination` argument, `NoConversion` is returned as expected.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here (and it's likely you won't -- there's not a lot of in-depth Roslyn knowledge here), try the #roslyn channel on the C# Discord: https://discord.com/invite/csharp. A lot of the compiler team hang out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is just a bog-standard cast of object to string, IE:

```cs
public string M(object o)
    => (string)o;
```

IE: At runtime, check if `o` is an instance of `string`. If it is, return it as `string`. If it isn't, throw `InvalidCastException`.

Specifically you're seeing this case from §10.3.5 Explicit reference conversions:

> - From object and dynamic to any other *reference_type*.

You don't see the conversion with your user-defined class because it's more specific than `object` (and as such is known to never have a reference conversion to `string`.)